# Run command output lines as another command in linux

Tags: bash, command, xargs

I am running this command :

`find ./  -type f -printf "wc -l \"%p\"\n"`

which gives this output:

```
wc -l "ANLS 457567.pl"
wc -l "ANLS 457567.pl"
```

Now I want to run this whole line as another command.

How can I achieve this?

I know that I can use `xargs` to pass its output as arguments to another command  but out of curiosity I want to know if that (**Run command output lines as another command**) is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass it to shell's STDIN:

```
find ./  -type f -printf "wc -l \"%p\"\n" | sh
```

or if the shell supports process substitution, `<()`:

```
sh <(find ./  -type f -printf "wc -l \"%p\"\n")
```

---

With just `find`:

```
find ./  -type f -exec wc -l {} +
```

Comment: `find ./  -type f -printf "wc -l \"%p\"\n" | sh` This works exactly like I needed.

Answer (score 3):

While you can pipe commands like that to a shell, it may get <strike>somewhat</strike> very problematic, since any globs and variables and others will be expanded.

File names containing e.g. asterisks (`*`, glob) or dollar signs (`$`, variable and command expansion) will cause problems. You'd need to make sure to quote everything correctly, and in the general case your file names can contain quotes themselves, so it's not that easy.

---

But in the case of `find`, it can execute external commands itself:

```
find ./  -type f -exec wc -l {} \;
```

the `{}` is replaced by the current file name, and the (quoted) semicolon at the end is required.

At least some versions of `find` support an alternate format which gives multiple file names to command in one go, saving a bunch of executions:

```
find ./  -type f -exec wc -l {} \+
```

Answer (score 0):

See @ilkkachu comment for the practical solution for this case. But otherwise, the shell expands the variables before executing each line, so

```
find ./  -type f -printf "wc -l %p\n" | while read line; do
    $line
done
```

will work just fine (unless special characters are found in filenames - like spaces).

Notice how `$line` has no quotes around, and we haven't quoted `%p` either. That's because we **want** the shell to split the line into words before execution -- treating the words of `$line` as the command and its arguments, just as if you wrote them yourself. That's why spaces don't work.

This is avoided by using the shell built-in `eval`, which *really* does work just like you typed the command into the shell - including the quotes (which are back now):

```
find ./  -type f -printf "wc -l \"%p\"\n" | while read line; do
    eval $line
done
```

This last one should work in all cases - but still isn't a good practice. `eval` should be the last resort. I'm including these options just so you know they work, but there are usually better ways, such as the `-exec` option of `find`.

Comment: ` find ./  -type f -printf "wc -l \"%p\"\n" |head| while read line; do $line; done` is giving me this error:
`wc: '"./457567/ANLS_457567.pl"': No such file or directory`

Comment: that won't work if the file name contains whitespace, since _quotes inside a variable don't work_. if the input is, say `wc -l "foo bar"`, it gets turned into `wc`, `-l`, `"foo`, `bar"` after the variable is split along words. (that's "<quote>foo" as one argument, and "bar<quote>" as another)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to remove the quotes from the `printf` statement. Yes, this splitting here does not obey hard-coded quotes (in this respect, it's not the same as just typing it into the shell, the quotes stay in the argument, so the file is not found).